# "-bash: /usr/bin/: No such file or directory" for almost every command

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

I made a mistake and ran this command on my Ubuntu-Precise:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all libc6
```

Consequently all of the packages with a dependency to `libc6` are removed, and whatever command I run, I get

```
-bash: /usr/bin/MY_COMMAND: No such file or directory
```

I can access the `/bin/busybox` but then when I want to reinstall `libc6` package via

```
/bin/busybox dpkg --force-depends -i install libc6
```

I get `"permission denied"`.

But the `Sudo` command doesn't work either!!

Does anyone has a suggestion on how I can install unistalled packages!

Comment: `bash` _programming_ is okay for SO but this is more of a sysadmin question. You may get a more targetted answer over on superuser or askubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

1. this is definitely not a bash programming question
2. you've done the one thing that should never be done on a linux system (even deleting the kernel is less trouble to repair - except if you reboot).[1]
3. the **only** solution you have left: reinstall your system.

The glibc is the only dependence that **ALL** your program have on your system (exception made for busybox which is statically compiled). So there not a single program that can work on your system, and all your apt/dpkg dependancies are broken. And afaict, busybox can't deal with all of that. And if you logout, you won't be able to login again.

[1] We used to recommend that on usenet in the 1990s to people that were too dumb to use a linux system, as we used to say, that's the best way to solve all your problems. We even wrote a [glibc uninstall howto](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pafoo.net%2Funinstallglibc%2Funinstglibc.html).

It was also a proof that people do not read howtos from start to end: *Use of this HOWTO can bring damage to your Linux installation. Use it only if you understand what you are doing. When in doubt, read the "man page" of the command that you use carefully.*